# Sort a dataframe in R by a dynamic set of columns named in another data frame

Tags: r

I have some data:

```
dd <- data.frame(cbind(c("A", "A", "B"), c("F", "E", "D"), c(1, 2, 3)))
names(dd) <- c("colA", "colB", "colC")
```

and I have a lookup frame lk

```
lk <- data.frame(rbind(c("colA", "colC"), c("colB", "colC")))
names(lk) <- c("srt_col", "srt_metric")
```

And what I want to do, is sort the data, by the columns named in the lookup frame.

Something like:

```
dd[ order(lk[, 1]), ]
```

which should give an output of

```
output data (roughly, you get the idea I hope)
A  E  2
A  F  1
B  D  3
```

but I can't seem to get the right syntax, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.  Can anyone help here?

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284042/replace-values-from-list-into-numbers-then-perform-arithmetic-calculation) work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a stab at it.

```
dd[do.call(order, dd[as.character(lk[, 1])]), ]
```

The `as.character` is to avoid any possible `factor` shenanigans.

Comment: Which raises the question - what is the point of `lk$srt_metric`?